# Parsing Razor Pages or Razor project in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, razor, razorengine

I am trying to set up a WPF application that is supposed to parse razor pages. Essentially I want to create templates in Razor Pages, and add the UI of WPF. I have developed some templates in razor formats. How can I parse them in my WPF project? Is it even possible?